# Como fazer para que um Edit não perder o foco?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Como fazer para um `TEdit`, que esteja sendo acessado no Android, não perca o foco por conta do teclado virtual que surge no momento que o foco vai para o `TEdit`?

Comment: Com "foco" vc diz que quando sobe o teclado, a TEdit "some" da tela e fica escondido atrás do teclado?

Comment: Não... Eu disse que no momento que acessa o edit o foco some do edit na hora que o teclado aparece.

Comment: Edit1.SetFocus no OnEnter não resolveria?

Comment: não já testei assim e não fica pelo menos não aparece o cursor piscando indicando que o foco esta no Edit

Comment: Apos validar no onExit(), se o valor estiver inválido e nao desejar que o mesmo perca o foco, utilize como ultima linha no onExit(): Abort;

Answer (score 0):

Você está se referindo a um `EditText`? Caso sim, no local do seu código que faz com que seu `EditText` perca o foco, você pode tentar adicionar:

```
editText.requestFocus();
```

Provavelmente deve funcionar (manter o foco do elemento). Caso não funcione, dê uma olhada nessas soluções:

[*Android Edittext looses focus while typing in the keypad*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810103/android-edittext-looses-focus-while-typing-in-the-keypad)

[*Focus removed while typing in edit text*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649194/focus-removed-while-typing-in-edit-text)

Comment: Isso funciona no Delphi?

Comment: Não estou me referindo ao `EditText` pois no Delphi não tem esse componente.